# Xcode 4.4 - push 'continue' repeatedly to pass each and every breakpoint

Tags: xcode

There's some new strange behavior in Xcode 4.4 (Mountain Lion) I'm hoping someone knows how to fix.

Every time I set a breakpoint, when the debugger reaches that breakpoint and pauses, I have to push 'continue' 5-10 times to actually proceed past the breakpoint.

Now, it doesn't appear to actually be refusing to do anything for the first 9 clicks.  Rather, (and this is critical) although the bold **this part is your code** lines don't change at all, the apple internal dispatch threads do change.

For example:

[image]

It's almost as if the 'continue' action is continuing deeper through a stack of apple internal calls which exist between when the last piece of *my code* that called the breakpoint was called and when the *breakpoint* was called.

Anyway, it makes using breakpoints impossible, as I can't actually keep track of program execution and am clicking 100s of times for every build.  New in 4.4!

Anybody experienced this?  Any ideas on how to fix?